# Screen geometry transposed under Weston with fbdev transform=90 in Qt 5.9

Tags: c++, qt, screen-orientation, wayland

I have an embedded device where I use Qt 5.9 and Weston. Weston has to use fbdev backend (reasons out of scope) and needs

```
transform=90
```

in its output section, otherwise the screen is rotated. It runs fine, but I am unable to get a propper screen size in Qt. To run my application in fullscreen in Qt 5.8 I used:

```
auto geometry = QGuiApplication::screens().first()->geometry();
view.setGeometry(geometry);
```

and it was ok. With Qt 5.9 the screen reports its size transposed, so I would have to use

```
auto geometry = QGuiApplication::screens().first()->geometry();
geometry = geometry.transposed();
view.setGeometry(geometry);
```

This runs fine again, but the application is no longer portable. I use it on other platforms as well, all work without correctly without transposing.

Looking into the weston log I see

```
fbdev output 480×854 px
```

which corresponds to what I get in Qt now. But how to properly detect the rotation caused by `transform=90`?